# Dynamic text for subtitle for Layout in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, dynamic-text

I am preparing some layouts (different paper sizes and formats) in ArcMap 10.8 to be published in WebGIS for the printer widget application under WebGIS.

In one part I have to add the title and subtitle to the layout and I have used the following codes for them :

`<dyn type="document" property="title"/>`
`<dyn type="document" property="subtitle"/>`

Afte publishing and running the printer widget in WebGIS, the title appears normally but the subtitle does not appear.

I have tried to change the text boundary, size, ... but it does nt work.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Where did you find the subtitle property and its availability as dynamic text documented?

Comment: Just to elaborate...  I don't think that there is any such dynamic text property as 'subtitle'.  You can see all of the properties listed at:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/working-with-dynamic-text.htm .

Where have you entered the subtitle text?

If you have entered it into an attribute and are using data driven pages, then you could use a data driven page attribute with dynamic text:  `<dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="<Field Name>" domainlookup="true"/>`